# MS Access SQL code - Changing data in the rows already in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying this code to update the a table called "sec0411_employees that has a "credit_limit" column.

**update sec0411_employees
set credit_limit = ‘27.00’
where credit_limit in ‘15.00’;**

Here is the data, notice multiple entries of '15.00' in the credit_limit column.

Thanks for any help!

Paul

[image]

Comment: Wow... your amazing! It updated the 3 rows! Thanks so much... I guess my apostrophes around '27.00' and '15.00' were throwing errors. Your the best... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
update sec0411_employees
    set credit_limit = 27.00
    where credit_limit = 15.00;
```

Comment: Wow... your amazing! It updated the 3 rows. Thanks so munch!